# match products in a list both in their singular and plural forms in R

Tags: r

I have to classify a list of products like these:

```
product_list<-data.frame(product=c('banana from ecuador 1 unit', 'argentinian meat (1 kg) cow',
'chicken breast','noodles','salad','chicken salad with egg','chicken breasts','eggs from chickens'))
```

Based on the words included in each element of this vector:

```
product_to_match<-c('cow meat','deer meat','cow milk','chicken breast','chicken egg salad','anana')
```

I have to match a product `(for example: chicken egg)` having in mind that the ones writing the products might write the both in `singular/plural` and in different orders. So they might write `'chickens egg'`, `'chicken eggs'`, `'egg chicken'` and so on.

As I see it, given certain product like `'chicken egg'`, I have to have:

1. An `'AND'` condition, where the product listed includes all the `N` words. In this case it would have to have the words `'egg'` and `'chicken'`.
2. An `'OR'` condition, since each word may appear in both singular or plural, like `'egg'` and `'eggs'`.

I am looking to label each row of `product_list`, having something like this:

```
product_list<-data.frame(product=c('banana from ecuador 1 unit', 'argentinian meat (1 kg) cow','chicken breast',
'noodles','salad','chicken salad with egg','chicken brests','eggs from chickens'),class=c(NA,'cow meat','chicken breast',
NA,NA,'chicken egg salad','chicken breast','chicken egg'))
```

Notice that `'anana'` did not match with `'banana'`, even though the characters are included in the string but not the word.

I was able to achieve some results splitting the products in words, and then checking which ones match, but I had some troubles with plurals. I know that regex might be useful here, but I could not figure out how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try `outer` + `strsplit` + `grepl` like below

```
q <- outer(
  strsplit(product_to_match, "\\s+"),
  strsplit(product_list$product, "\\s+"),
  FUN = Vectorize(function(a, b) all(sapply(a, function(x) any(grepl(paste0("\\b", x), b)))))
)
product_list$class <- product_to_match[replace(colSums(q * row(q)), colSums(q) == 0, NA)]
```

which gives

```
> product_list
                      product             class
1  banana from ecuador 1 unit              <NA>
2 argentinian meat (1 kg) cow          cow meat
3              chicken breast    chicken breast
4                     noodles              <NA>
5                       salad              <NA>
6      chicken salad with egg chicken egg salad
7             chicken breasts    chicken breast
8          eggs from chickens              <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid regular expressions you could try word stemming instead. This would allow you to find some irregular pluralisations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(SnowballC)

wordStem(c("lady", "ladies"))
# [1] "ladi" "ladi"

product_list <- tibble(product = c('banana from ecuador 1 unit', 
    'argentinian meat (1 kg) cow', 'chicken breast',
    'noodles','salad','chicken salad with egg',
    'chicken breasts','eggs from chickens'), 
    id = seq_along(product))
product_to_match <- tibble(product_group = c('cow meat','deer meat',
        'cow milk','chicken breast','chicken egg salad','anana'), 
    pid = seq_along(product_group))
```

The **tidytext** package provides a framework for converting documents to tokens/words.

```
# convert to tidy word lists
tidy_products <- product_list %>% 
    unnest_tokens(output = word, input = product)
tidy_products
# # A tibble: 23 x 2
#       id word       
#    <int> <chr>      
#  1     1 banana     
#  2     1 from       
#  3     1 ecuador    
#  4     1 1          
#  5     1 unit       
#  6     2 argentinian
#  7     2 meat       
#  8     2 1          
#  9     2 kg         
# 10     2 cow        
# # … with 13 more rows
```

`SnowballC::wordStem` performs the truncation.

```
tidy_products <- mutate(tidy_products, 
    word = wordStem(word))
tail(tidy_products)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#      id word   
#   <int> <chr>  
# 1     6 egg    
# 2     7 chicken
# 3     7 breast 
# 4     8 egg    
# 5     8 from   
# 6     8 chicken

# same processing for products
tidy_match <- product_to_match %>% 
    unnest_tokens(output = word, input = product_group) %>% 
    mutate(word = wordStem(word))
```

From here you could check equality of complete strings, e.g. using the match operator `%in%`. By this approach we are matching whether all words are present in any order. Note that products may be contained in other products e.g. cow meat and cow meat burger, so the order of the match data frame is important.

```
# choose first match
# matchdf must have columns word and pid
first_product_id <- function(string, matchdf) {
    out <- NA
    for (pid in split(matchdf, f = matchdf$pid)) {
        is_in <- pid$word %in% string
        if (length(is_in) == 0) { is_in <- FALSE }
        if (all(is_in)) {
            out <- pid$pid[1]
            break
        }
    }
    out
}
first_product_id(string = tidy_products$word[tidy_products$id == 3], 
    matchdf = tidy_match)
# [1] 4

# look up table where words are in 
lut <- tidy_products %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(
        pid = first_product_id(string = word, matchdf = tidy_match))

product_list %>% 
    left_join(lut, by = "id") %>% 
    left_join(product_to_match, by = "pid")
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
# product                          id   pid product_group    
# <chr>                         <int> <int> <chr>            
# 1 banana from ecuador 1 unit      1    NA NA               
# 2 argentinian meat (1 kg) cow     2     1 cow meat         
# 3 chicken breast                  3     4 chicken breast   
# 4 noodles                         4    NA NA               
# 5 salad                           5    NA NA               
# 6 chicken salad with egg          6     5 chicken egg salad
# 7 chicken breasts                 7     4 chicken breast   
# 8 eggs from chickens              8    NA NA
```